# Dynamic XML documents instead of `.ui` files in Qt

Tags: c++, xml, qt, user-interface, xquery

The class [`QUiLoader`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/quiloader.html) represents elements of a graphical user interface, of Qt components, described by an XML document. A common design pattern would be a build process integrating a static document into the application as a resource. Another would be code generation at build time.

Consider the possibility of describing part of a user interface through an XML document that would be dynamically constructed, such as through an [XSLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT) transformation provided by [Xalan-C++](https://apache.github.io/xalan-c/). In an XML-driven application, such a design opens possibilities not readily available from more widespread patterns.

Yet, it may appear from the documentation that the only interface for passing XML data to be utilized by `QUiLoader` is through the invocation of the method [`load()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/quiloader.html#load) invoked by passing an instance of [`QIODevice`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qiodevice.html). Such a call supports streaming data of serialized form. Naturally, intermediary serialization or parsing operations are unnecessary, at least in principle, and unpreferred.

Following are two questions:

1. Is such a strategy viable, in terms of authoring a Qt application for which some of the presentation layout is resolved dynamically in such a manner?
2. Is a superior approach available, for displaying presentation represented by a dynamically-generated XML document, compared to passing a string representation of it, through Qt?

Answer (score 0):

> Is such a strategy viable, in terms of authoring a Qt application for which some of the presentation layout is resolved dynamically in such a manner?

No. You'd generally programmatically interact with `QWidget`s to achieve dynamic content. `QUiLoader` uses `QXmlStreamReader` (the Qt SAX parser) to load the xml, so can't operate on a (generic) dom document anyway.

> Is a superior approach available, by addressing the more general objectives through a broader range of tools and patterns, compared to passing a string representation of an XML document?

You can write regular C++ functions that construct (parts of) your UI.

> In application development, a common design pattern would be a build process integrating a static document into the application as a resource.

That's not how Qt deals with static UIs. There is a `.ui` -> `.cpp` compiler, `uic`, which is part of the build process. It generates a (long, boring) function that constructs the widgets and sets their properties.

Comment: I'm sorry, but both parts of the answer appear to miss the crux of the question, how a Qt application might display an interface represented by documents of the design language generated on-the-fly. Code expressing regular function calls, whether manually-written, or automatically-generated at build time, is not the topic of the question.

Comment: @brainchild the transformations you could apply to a `.ui` file with xslt are a subset of the transformations you can apply to a runtime `QWidget` with code. And I didn't miss the question, my answer is you *wouldn't do that*

Comment: The projects you can create in Qt. C++, XML, or XSLT, are a subset of those you can create in assembly, but I am asking you please to stay on topic, rather than changing it. Especially without your knowing details of the broader project, telling me what I want to do, or telling me what question I am asking, is not helpful.

Comment: I revised the question to make the intention more explicit.

Comment: @brainchild see [What is the XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I don't think manipulating `.ui` files at runtime is an appropriate solution to any problem

Comment: I know about the XY Problem. I'm sorry, but you're applying inferences beyond those supported by available premises, including speculating about the depth of my comprehension. Please consider the [argument from ignorance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_from_ignorance).

Comment: @brainchild the short answer to "can I avoid serialising/deserialising my intermediate xml?" is "No, not without re-implementing `QUiLoader` yourself"

Comment: Re-implementing in the sense of rewriting the core logic scratch (or as a fork of the original source), right?